# Property of distance and adherence

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Please how to prove that in a metric space $(E,d),$ for $A,B\subseteq E$ that

$\forall x\in E, d(x,A)=d(x,\overline{A})$ and that $d(A,B)=d(A,\overline{B})=d(\overline{A},\overline{B})$

and  $$\overline{A}=\overline{B}\Longleftrightarrow \forall x\in E, d(x,A)= d(x,B).$$
For the fist I know that $A\subset \overline{A}$ so $d(x,\overline{A})\leq d(x,A)$.

I think that $d(A,B)=\inf_{A} d(a,B)=\inf_{A} d(a,\overline{B})=d(A,\overline{B})$ (using the first equality).

But I don't know how to continue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d(A,B)\ge d(\overline A, \overline B)$ true trivially, for the other direction let $\varepsilon>0$, then there are $x\in\overline A$, $y\in\overline B$ such that $d(x,y)\le d(\overline A, \overline B)+\varepsilon$. There are also $a\in A$, $b\in B$ such that $d(x,a)\le\varepsilon$ and $d(y,b)\le\varepsilon$. Using the triangle inequality we have
$$d(A,B)\le d(a,b)\le d(a,x)+d(x,y)+d(y,a)\le\varepsilon+(d(\overline A, \overline B)+\varepsilon)+\varepsilon=d(\overline A,\overline B)+3\varepsilon$$
The inequality follows by letting $\varepsilon\to 0$.

$d(x,A)=d(x,\overline A)$ is just a special case of this for $B=\{x\}$.

If $\overline A=\overline B$, then for any $x\in E$ we have $d(x,A)=d(x,\overline A)=d(x,\overline B)=d(x,B)$. For the other direction, let $x\in\overline A$, then $0=d(x,\overline A)=d(x,A)=d(x,B)=d(x,\overline B)$, so $x\in\overline B$, therefore $\overline A\subseteq\overline B$; the other inclusion is analogical.

Comment: why this $\varepsilon$ exist ?

Comment: i mean why we can do this ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Do real numbers exist? If yes, then we can choose any positive real number we like.

Comment: can we use sequences i mean if $y\in \overline{A}$ then there existe a sequence $(y_n)$ in $A$ such that $y_n\rightarrow y$

Comment: @Vrouvrou I guess you can if it helps you. Replace $\varepsilon$ by $\frac1n$ in the above proof and let $n\to\infty$.

Comment: for $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $x\in \overline{A}$ or $x\in A$ ??? please

Comment: @Vrouvrou Exactly as is written, $x,y$ come from a property of infimums: $d(\overline A,\overline B)+\varepsilon > d(\overline A,\overline B) = \inf\{d(x,y)\mid x\in\overline A, y\in\overline B\}$.

Comment: if i want to prove that $d(x,A)\leq d(x,\overline{A})$ i say for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $a\in A$ such that $d(x,\overline{A})+\varepsilon\geq d(x,a)$ as $d(x,A)\leq d(x,a)$ we obtain the result when $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$ right ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Yes, but why do you need to do that? You can see that in my proof I already start with proving $d(A, B)=d(\overline A, \overline B)$ and what you say follows from setting $A=\{x\}$ (then also $\overline A=\{x\}$ since points are closed).

Comment: Ok, but please i know that $B\subset \overline{B}, A\subset \overline {A}$ so $d(x,\overline{A})\leq d(x,A)$ and the same thing for $B$ but i can't write why $d(\overline{A},\overline{B})\leq d(A,B)$ please

Comment: @Vrouvrou The proof is in my answer. You need to learn basics of mathematical reasoning and understand all definitions clearly before asking these questions. I won't handhold you through every trivial step in this proof for it would take many pages of text and probably wouldn't help you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $a\in A$ such that
$$
 d(x,\bar A) \ge d(x,a) - \varepsilon.
$$

Comment: There exist $a$ from $\overline{A}$ or from $A$ ????